# Copy memory every n bytes

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I have one array of uint8_t values, my goal is to copy every 3 bytes to a dst array, but the catch is that I iterate from 4 to 4 bytes in the dst array, just like shown below.

```
src = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
dst = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
...
dst = {1,2,3,0,4,5,6,0}
```

For now i'm using the following code to perform this task.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr_size ; i++)
    memcpy(dst + i*4, arr_ptr + i*3, 3);
```

Is there are faster/efficient way to do this?

**Edit for more context:**

I have the following struct that's needed to be populated with data from an image array, where `a` will always be initialized with 0.

```
typedef struct {unsigned char r,g,b,a} uchar4;
...
// init dst
...
*dst = (uchar4 *)malloc(height * width * sizeof(uchar4));
```

By assigning values to the uchar4 array doing `struct.variable = value`, takes a lot of time, which led me to think that it would be faster to just copy the values from the image array, that stores uint8_t values, to the uchar4 array, since uchar and uint8 occupy 1 byte in memory. This way the structs array is initialized with 0's and every 3 bytes from the flattened image is paste every 4 bytes in the uchar arr.

**Edit2:** code corrections

Comment: This seems better suited at [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652), which happens often.

Comment: `memcpy(dst + i*3, arr_ptr + i*4, 3);` it will not do what you think it will

Comment: Yeah, I think you have 3 and 4 reversed in that `memcpy`.  And I don't think `arr_size` is the right upper bound for the loop as it stands. But I strongly suspect that even a naive implementation without `memcpy`, like in Erdal's answer, will be optimized well by a decent compiler.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ On the plus side, Some programmer dude did link to CR's "What topics can I ask about here?" instead of the main CR page. I typically do the same thing (to make it more likely that the asker sees that page).

Comment: `memcpy` wins in any competition.

Comment: I added more information for context

Comment: How large are the arrays? In the example you have 6 and 8 bytes, hardly anything to optimize.

Comment: @chqrlie 1080*1920*3 bytes

Comment: @GustavoStahl can it be done by the hardware? For example many uCs have special DMA hardware for that. STM32 for example has DMA2D which can convert from RGB to RGBA, automatically use LUT tables and merge layers without using the core processor.

Comment: @0___________ I don't know how the LUT would be useful for, since the RGB values are defined. The 'A' channel, as in the uchar struct, is not important, so much is that I define as 0's. If the DMA that you talked about can pad the flattened input image with 0's, it would save me the work of using the ```memcpy```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to try and optimize your conversion loop. As recommended by *0___________*, you should consider `memcpy` for sized sized chunks as most optimizers will generate very efficient code for the target platform, beating hand coded naive alternatives.

Here is a quick benchmark comparing 3 methods:

- copying 3 bytes explicitly, incrementing pointers.
- using `memcpy` for this copy

Other methods can be added, such as trying to take advantage of SIMD instructions, which should provide significant performance improvements at the expense of portability.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct rgb {
    uint8_t r, g, b;
} rgb;

typedef struct rgba {
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
} rgba;

void copy3to4_simple(void *to, const void *from, size_t count) {
    const uint8_t *src = from;
    uint8_t *dst = to;
    uint8_t *end = dst + count * 4;
    while (dst < end) {
        dst[0] = src[0];
        dst[1] = src[1];
        dst[3] = src[2];
        dst += 4;
        src += 3;
    }
}

void copy3to4_memcpy(void *to, const void *from, size_t count) {
    const uint8_t *src = from;
    uint8_t *dst = to;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        memcpy(dst + i * 4, src + i * 3, 3);
    }
}

int main() {
    int width = 1920, height = 1080;
    rgb *src = calloc(sizeof(*src), width * height);
    rgba *dst = calloc(sizeof(*dst), width * height);
    const char *name[10];
    clock_t c[10];
    int n = 0;

#define RUNS  100
    name[n] = "simple";
    for (int i = 0; i < RUNS + 10; i++) {
        if (i == 10)
            c[n] = -clock();
        copy3to4_simple(dst, src, width * height);
    }
    c[n++] += clock();

    name[n] = "memcpy";
    for (int i = 0; i < RUNS + 10; i++) {
        if (i == 10)
            c[n] = -clock();
        copy3to4_memcpy(dst, src, width * height);
    }
    c[n++] += clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s: %.3f msec\n", name[i], c[i] * 1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / RUNS);
    }
    free(src);
    free(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this on my old Macbook, I get this:

```
simple: 2.478 msec
memcpy: 1.840 msec
```

`memcpy` beats `simple` by 25%, but you might get a different result on a different architecture.

Comment: I just tried copy3to4_simple on my machine, it beats memcpy by ~1ms, since they are very similar in time spent i'll have my eyes on both, because they will be implemented on another machine, which runs intel btw. If you happen to know any other ways to improve this, i'll be glad (you mentioned SIMD instructions).

Comment: @GustavoStahl: I just posted a small improvement (on my machine) to `copy3to4_simple()`: comparing `dst` to the end of the array instead of decrementing `count`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `arr_size` is the number of triplets to be copied.

```
for(size_t i=0; i<arr_size ; i++)
    memcpy(dst + i*3, src + i*4, 3);
```

it is wrong it has to be

```
for(size_t i=0; i<arr_size ; i++)
    memcpy(dst + i*4, src + i*3, 3);
```

Now the context.

```
typedef struct {unsigned char r,g,b,a} uchar4;
```

It is not guaranteed that the compiler will not add any padding. And any pointer punning might not work correctly. Add static assert to check the size of your structure is 4, if not use you will need to use some compiler extension to pack the struct.

Efficiency:
It is very difficult to judge but the trivial functions with code from the answers here show that it is very likely the `memcpy` version to be the most efficient.

https://godbolt.org/z/E4s8sa

I have tried to remove one memory access and wrote this very bad (it invokes UBs! in general, but it will work on X86 and Cortex-M3 and newer). It was done just for the curiosity: ( WARNING!! Graphic programming content!!! Not suitable for all audience)https://godbolt.org/z/Pefc6T

Comment: @chqrlie I assume array_size as a number of triplets to be copied. IMO it is logical if we consider the context.

Comment: Makes sense, the size of an array of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `memcpy` at all. Just with pointer arithmetic, you could do the following:

```
uint8_t *src = some_values;
uint8_t *end = src + some_values_size;
uint8_t *dst = some_buffer;

for (; src < end; src += 3, dst += 4) {
    dst[0] = src[0];
    dst[1] = src[1];
    dst[2] = src[2];
}
```

With the example above, you could define the code as a macro and use it for different datatypes. `memcpy` wants to know how many bytes it has to copy, therefore you need a type.

**Note**: The code assumes that the length of the array `src` is a multiple of 3 and the length of the array `dst` equals to: `(length(src) / 3) * 4`.

Comment: If src is `31` long then `src[2]` will read past array (src[32]).

Comment: @Notinlist Yeah, you're absolute right. But i assumed that the source array is an array of a vector with 3 components and therefore the length of it as a multiple of three.

Comment: Copying byte by byte is slower than `memcpy` https://godbolt.org/z/9GhcK5. Do not be afraid of `memcpy`, be afraid of ***micro-optimizations*** as often they work the opposite way as expected. In `memcpy` we trust

Comment: I didn't said that using memcpy would be slower. I just said, that it is not necessary. And not using it, has the advantage to use the code as a macro (for different datatypes) without the need to specify the amount of bytes to copy.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük The question was what is more effective. Your solution is not. So the answer is wrong.

Comment: @0___________: did you actually benchmark the alternatives? the assembly listing alone is no proof of better performance, especially with current architectures :)

Comment: @chqrlie absolutely right but I am too lazy to test it and I trusted my instinct

Comment: @chqrlie I have measured it. Memcpy wins. 2.9 vs 2.1 seconds in some configuration. Similar results on another machine.

Comment: @Notinlist: I get similar results too. Posted a simple benchmark to try other methods... I am sure SIMD instructions can beat `memcpy` hands down (albeit non portably), but I'm not familiar with the Intel intrinsic functions.

Comment: @all I did some testing. For unsigned char, memcpy wins, but for other types (int, long), memcpy looses.

Comment: @0___________: you win, on my machine at least... Benchmark posted.

Comment: @chqrlie where is my trophy ?